# Spotify Web API Console

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, spotify, client-applications

I am curious about how to get Json from a windows forms project and using a webBrowser control to simulate access to a spotify app. I know I need to pass a string of some kind such as clientid=.... etc

> GET
>   https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/?client_id=5fe01282e44241328a84e7c5cc169165&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email&state=34fFs29kd09

How would I accomplish this using the code above?
Do I put it in  string and send it off to a url using the webbrowser and some how get a response form the webpage???

Could someone show me some example to try and accomplish this?
I am very confused.

I don't know how to use the "GET" command or any of those cURL commands. 
Another thing do I send the url to the webbrowser and have the response saved and try to seperate the Json that gets sent back?

Any help would be wonderful such as an explanation. 
Ultimately I am just trying to get information on how to access my APP I created in spotify and which url to use so that a user can login to my app and they get a token to use the webapi or so that I can use the web api.

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/

I am lost. Help. Please.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `how to access my APP I created in spotify` I don't understand.

Comment: Check out [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/), it makes this easy.  It's available as a nuget package.

Comment: I think you should start off with either a simple API to handle REST access and grow with the REST as you are more comfortable using it. Also, using Postman will help a lot with any specifics that you are having. Otherwise this is a very broad question.

Comment: What is postman?

Comment: Also I made a client app through spotify on their "Create an app" so I can get a client id and allow for token to be sent back to the user to be passed in a url so I can have access to the web api. :| I am lost on the